# How to set up a .ruby-version less strict?

Tags: ruby, rbenv

I like to setup the version of Ruby I am using on each project by setting up a `.ruby-version` file, but I find it very strict, especially if I am sharing my code.

If I declare this for example:

```
#.ruby-version
3.0.2
```

The code is going to request this ruby version and it won't accept any other no even: `3.0.4` which I know it will also work. This makes my code less sharable.

Is there any way I can use version description syntax like in the [Gemfile file](https://guides.rubygems.org/patterns/#pessimistic-version-constraint)?

- >= 3.0.0
- >= 3.0.2, < 3.3
- ~> 3.0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's funny that you even said "like in the Gemfile...", because **you can define the required ruby version in the `Gemfile`, *instead of* having a `.ruby-version` file:**

```
ruby '~> 3.0' # or whatever

gem 'some-dependency'
gem 'another-dependency'
# ...
```

Comment: Sadly this doesn't work for one important scenario. It works for the `bundle` commands but not for the `ruby` commands. Console `ruby` commands on this folder will ignore `Gemfile` settings :?

Comment: (1) Why are you running ruby commands in the project? It would be more normal to run commands like rails, rake, or - if you really need to - prefix any command (including ruby) with bundle exec - and there you go.

Comment: (2) if you still really want a .ruby-version file then that's fine, just remove it from source control (I.e. add it to the .gitignore) and you can continue with your old workflow without affecting other developers

Comment: (1) I use Ruby for more things than Rails. I do also scripting tools

Comment: (2) Thanks for the idea, I may use it. But it is not solving my question. I want to share the `.ruby-version` with other developers, just not make it so strict

Comment: A combination of (1) prefixing with `bundle exec` and (2) removing `.ruby-version` from the repo may be my solution. thanks

Comment: You could also consider using binstubs in the project to avoid needing an explicit bundle exec for all commands.

Answer (score 1):

When needed, I use the following directly inside scripts (Gem is part of ruby standard gems)

```
raise "Invalid Ruby version #{RUBY_VERSION}" if Gem::Version.new(RUBY_VERSION) < Gem::Version.new('3.3.0')
```

Note that you MUST not compare directly string version (will not work
when version fields have more than 1 digit E.g. 3.10.0).